# Webservice delphi soap com autenticação

Tags: delphi, web-service, autenticação, soap

Estou a usar o delphi para leitura de um webservice de um companhia de seguros.

Acontece que o mesmo vem em formato XML em SOAP.

Faço o import do WSDL consigo obter os métodos.

Mas para me ligar ao Web Service tenho de mandar um token que não sei como se faz na documentação tem um exemplo com o wfc strom e funciona. Tenho de criar um msgheader do tipo string onde mando o token.

Depois nos parâmetros da query, envio apenas o bi e id da companhia e me retorna dados, antes tenho de ir na config e colocar o user,pass e domínio para me ligar ao web service pois está no IIS.

Código delphi que não esta a funcionar

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, WSClientes, StdCtrls,
  InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, opCOnvertOptions, XMLIntf, XSBuiltIns,
  Soap.Rio;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TSOAPCredentials }


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
 ws   : WSClientes;

 Rio  : THTTPRIO;


begin
 Rio := THttpRIO.Create(nil);
 ws := WSClientes (false, '', Rio);

 ws :=WSClientes.MlBase2.Create;
 ws := WSClientes.GetIWSClientes();
 Rio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'dominio/user0121';
 Rio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'password';
 Rio.SOAPHeaders.ToString := 'L9+zby7w1V5OZTVGUPLZ1x8rJYzCEHAnxovPUuyadZFdbv21elZ1qsvy';
 Rio.SOAPHeaders.Send(Rio);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Meu exemplo de adição de um ***header*** ao objeto `HTTPRIO` para autenticação:

```
class function TCRMWebServices.GetFileTransferService(AUsername, APassword: string; ASendEvent: TPostingDataEvent): FileTransferServiceSoap;
var
  soapHeader: UserAuthentication;
  httpRio: THTTPRIO;
begin
  soapHeader := UserAuthentication.Create;
  soapHeader.Username := AUsername;
  soapHeader.Password := APassword;
  httpRio := GetHTTPRIO('Services/FileTransferService.asmx', soapHeader);
  if Assigned(ASendEvent) then
    httpRio.HTTPWebNode.OnPostingData := ASendEvent;
  result := httpRio as FileTransferServiceSoap;
end;

class function TCRMWebServices.GetHTTPRIO(AServicePath: string; ASOAPHeader: UserAuthentication): THTTPRIO;
begin
  if Trim(AServicePath) = '' then
    AServicePath := 'WebService.asmx';
  result := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  result.URL := 'http://' + TCRMWebConfig.GetWebHostname + '/' + AServicePath;
  if ASOAPHeader <> nil then
    result.SOAPHeaders.Send(ASOAPHeader as TSOAPHeader);
end;
```

O primeiro método que é de onde obtenho uma instância do HTTPRIO já setado para o WebService que desejo adiciona cria uma instância de uma classe do tipo `TSOAPHeader`, a `UserAuthentication`.

Essa classe possui as propriedades `Username` e `Password` que preciso informar segundo especificações.

Você provavelmente ao fazer o parser do WSDL deve ter recebido uma classe que herda de `TSOAPHeader` também e essa tem a propriedade que você precisa informar o ***token***.

O Segundo método, o `GetHTTPRIO` mostra no final como adicionar o ***Header*** ao `HTTPRIO`:

```
result.SOAPHeaders.Send(ASOAPHeader as TSOAPHeader);
```

`Result`, que é o objeto `HTTPRIO` em si, `.SOAPHeaders.Send(ASOAPHeader as TSOAPHeader);`

Veja se encontra essa classe e teste desta forma como demonstrei.

Claro que após obter uma instância do `HTTPRIO` em uma variável do tipo da ***interface*** referente ao Web Service você precisa executar o método desejado.

Veja que meu primeiro método retorna o tipo `FileTransferServiceSoap` que é uma ***interface*** com os métodos disponibilizados pelo ***WebService***.

Logo, eu tenho algo como:

```
var 
  service: FileTransferServiceSoap;
begin
  ...
  service := TCRMWebService.GetFileTransferService(username, password, evento);
  service.SendFile(file);
end;
```

Isso é algo que não vi em seu código de exemplo e também gostaria de citar que o método que está a obter uma instância de `HTTPRIO` e do cliente do ***WebService*** estão confusas.

---

### Tentando ajudar

Só para completar, e tentar ajudar:

provalmente sua declaração:

```
var
  ws: WSClientes;
```

Já te dá ws como sendo `WSClientes` o tipo do ***WebService***.

Onde você obtém:

```
ws := WSClientes(false, '', Rio);
```

Me baseando na `unit` que a ferramenta do **Delphi** gera, então:
- `ws` Provavelmente já é o cliente do ***WebService*** instânciado.
- Você está passando o objeto `HTTPRIO` para ele. Então você pode tentar adicionar o ***Header*** antes de passar para essa função.

Depois basta executar o método do ***WebService*** que deseja, como exemplo:

```
clientes := ws.ObterClientes();
```

Acredito agora que tem informações mais que suficientes.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Por que fizeste [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/47835) alteração na pergunta?

Comment: @jbueno somente para destacar a parte que realmente é necessário

Comment: sim.detesto delphi

Comment: o wsclientes é o objecto gerado,agora falta  a autenticação

Comment: onde é que passo o token?

Comment: @user2964140 não tem uma classe herdada de TSOAPHeader?

Comment: não sou um leigo nos web services

Comment: ok.. sinto por qualquer coisa.. Eu infelizmente sem mais informações não posso ajudar.

Comment: como faço para ir buscar o tsoapheader declaração. eu no objecto HTTPRIO ja tenho o user e password colocas nas propriedades do objecto

Comment: @user2964140, se não me engano, esse usuário e senha colocados no componente HTTPRIO são para proxy.. Quando você usa a ferramenta do Delphi para efetuar o parser de uma wsdl, e há uso de SOAPHeaders nos services, a unit gerada pelo Delphi terá uma classe herdada de TSOAPHeader. No meu exemplo, `UserAuthentication` é uma classe herdada de `TSOAPHeader`, tipo `UserAuthentication = class(TSOAPHeader);`

Comment: ok então não coloco na nas propriedades do HHTPRIO.tem de em codigo.